# Need some type of IF...MOVE

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In a range of G4:G19, I am looking for "Winner" and when I find it, I want to MOVE (from the same row), the information in column D of that row to the cell in which I am writing the formula.

```
=IF(LARGE(G$4:G$19,1)="Winner", ...)
```

... move the contents in column D (of that row) to D25 which is where I want to place the formula.

I cannot be specific about the cell because it will be different depending on the cell that contains "Winner".

I need some kind of move statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using `LARGE`, since it only works with numbers, and so only returns numbers, which don't make sense to compare with the text "Winner", but...

From the what you've described, it sounds like something like the following formula in cell D25...

`=INDEX(D$4:D$19,MATCH("Winner",G$4:G$19,0),1)`

...might meet your needs.  The `MATCH` expression finds the relative position of the first cell it finds containing the exact (indicated by the 0) text "Winner" (case-insensitive) in the range G$4:G$19.  The `INDEX` expression returns the value in this row and the first column (indicated by the 1) of the range D$4:D$19.